# app engine php file_get_contents() returned 404

Tags: php, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, google-cloud-storage

I am using app engine of PHP for accessing files on Google Cloud Storage (GCS)

I uploaded files with "public-read" ACL via gsutil, but while I want to access the file within GAE via file_get_contents("gs://bucket-name/filename.ext") it shows 404 not found, which the GCS bucket and app engine are within same project.

Here's ACL of uploaded files on GCS:

```
[
  {
    "entity": "user-00b4903a97b3944a025a4a20295e......087da9a7daec544d40d51",
    "entityId": "00b4903a97b3944a025a4a20295e......087da9a7daec544d40d51",
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "allUsers",
    "role": "READER"
  },
  {
    "email": "blah-app-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    "entity": "blah-app-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    "role": "OWNER"
  }
]
```

I tried to add service account of app engine (blah@appspot.gserviceaccont.com) into owners of bucket permission list but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you double check the bucket & file name. It'd return 403 not 404 if it's an ACL issue.

Comment: Turns out it's ACL issue. I try not upload files by using `public-read` but inherit the bucket default permission, then it works.